# Class F and inverse F power amplifiers

Tags: electrical

These amplifiers tend to shape the current and voltage waveforms using their respective harmonics .

The goal is to minimize the area of overlap between drain (or collector) voltage and drain current to maximize efficiency.

My question is:  Would that make sense and work only if the transistor is meant to operate at full swing into the compression region ( almost as a switch but not quite) or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

They use polyharmonic resonant striplines to tune harmonics.  e.g.  A gate voltage condition to meet is that the impedance is a short circuit at the third harmonic.

e.g. a bare-die, Cree CGH40010F  model is developed for this transistor is focused on accurately predicting the on-off regions of the transistor characteristics as a switch.

An infinite number of **odd-harmonic resonators** results in an idealized **Class F mode** with a square voltage waveform and a half-sinusoidal current waveform at the device output terminal.

An infinite number of **even-harmonic resonators**
results in an idealized **inverse Class F mode**
with a half-sinusoidal voltage waveform and a
square current waveform at the device output
terminal

Answer (score 0):

> Would that make sense and work only if the transistor is meant to
>   operate at full swing into the compression region ( almost as a switch
>   but not quite) or otherwise?

Class F is basically Class B with harmonic tuning to shape the voltage. The output is passed through tuned circuits which block odd harmonics and reflect them back to the transistor's Drain/Collector, causing the normally half-sine voltage waveform to become a square wave with sharper sides that minimize the overlap between voltage and current (which causes power loss). It is intended to operate in the linear region, like Class B but with higher efficiency.

Overdriving Class F effectively turns it into a switching amplifier that is not linear (output amplitude not proportional to input amplitude), and does not significantly increase power output or efficiency.

In Class F<sup>-1</sup> the output *current* is a square wave and *even* harmonics are blocked, shaping the output voltage into a half-sine wave. Class F<sup>-1</sup> is designed to work with the transistor acting as a switch, so overdriving it with sine wave input *does* increase output power because it increases the conduction angle, producing higher output power and efficiency than Class F in compression.